# Setting zmin/zmax in groupplot confuses colorbar creation (colorbar is 3d)

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

When using `groupplot`s and setting `zmin` and/or `zmax` in the `groupplot` environment manually, `pgfplots` generates a (broken) 3d legend:

[image: Issue]

I assume the issue is that `groupplot` passes the `zmin`/`zmax` settings to the `colorbar` axis environment as well, resulting in the existential crisis making the colorbar 3d.

Omitting the settings from the global `groupplot` environment and passing them manually to each `\nextgroupplot` works. But I thought this was still worth posting in case there's a better solution or in case this is a bug that needs to be resolved.

## MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{groupplot}[%
    group style={
      group size=2 by 1,
      horizontal sep=2cm,
    },
    zmin=-10,
    zmax=10,
    colorbar horizontal,
  ]

    \nextgroupplot
    % \nextgroupplot[zmin=-10,zmax=10] % Works if global zmin/zmax are commented out.
      \addplot3[surf] {x+y};

    \nextgroupplot
    % \nextgroupplot[zmin=-10,zmax=10] % Works if global zmin/zmax are commented out.
      \addplot3[surf] {x+y};

  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the options are not reset for `colorbar`.

I have fixed this in `pgfplots`. You can activate the fix in your tex files by means of

```
\pgfplotsset{
    every colorbar global/.append style={
        zmin=,zmax=,
    }
}
```

Adding this to your preamble leads to

[image]